# Relational database how should be used

Tags: sql, mongodb, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

[image]I want to ask whether would be appropiate to use mysql and how it could should look if I want to store a table which looks like:

```
Table Food:
-totalCalories
-element1 => totalCal
-element2 => totalCal
-element3 => totalCal
```

For elements I would need to have a list and also for each element to have a value associated.
Please let me know how could I design a relational database according to atleast the first 1-2 normalization..
Each table could have different number of elements.
Thank you.
**PS:** What do you about this to have an Element table which would contain a row for each element with details from Food table ?

Comment: Can one food have many elements?

Comment: What is your 1 (clear specific researched non-duplicate) question? Where are you 1st stuck following what textbook/method? Otherwise you are just asking us to rewrite one with a bespoke tutorial--that's too broad. [ask] [Help] PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have created three tables

1. foods

- id (int auto increment primary key)
- name (varchar)
- total_calories (int)

2. elements

- id (int auto increment primary key)
- name (varchar)

3. food_element

- id (int auto increment primary key)
- food_id (foreign key -> food id)
- element_id (foreign key -> element id)